# Как передать значение GET через header(Location)?

Tags: php, redirect, header

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Если пользователь находится на странице, у которой есть параметр `GET`, как например `.php?article=51` и хочет авторизоваться на сайте с этой странице, то после нажатия на кнопку авторизации на этой же странице, он перенаправляется на главную, а не на текущую, с которой решил авторизоваться.

Хочу написать код, который будет перенаправлять его на туже страницу, но `header` не передает значение `GET`. Вот пример  кода с header

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    $login = $_SESSION['login'];

    if(тут должна быть проверка на текущую страницу) {
        header ('Location: pages/track.php?track='параметр GET);
    }
    echo 'Hello' . $_SESSION['track'] . "";

    exit();
}
```

Или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: вы в браузере откройте вкладку инструментов - сеть. И смотрите как там ваши запросы перекидываются. Видимо у вас там будет более двух 300 ответов. коли в итоге попадаете на главную, значит это `track.php` вас туда отправляет.

Comment: во вкладке сеть - пусто совсем. Проблемы с передачей GET в header

Comment: Как сделал я. На страницу авторизации в get параметре передаётся адрес страницы, на которую нужно перенаправить. После успешной авторизации перенаправляем на страницу, которая в параметре была. Если параметра нет, то на главную

Comment: ArchDemon а можете пример свеого кода написать?